# Salting Pork Chops

Tags: salt, pork, pork-chops

I have this idea of how I want to make pork chops. I don't know if it is a good idea so I'm asking about it here.

I want to take about two kg of pork chops, salt them with kosher salt for about two hours. Afterwards I want to get a vinegar bath and rinse all the excess salt of the meat.

The last step is to hang it in the fridge for a couple of days to dry the meat further.

I'm wondering if this is going to lead to good chops, whether I would still have to cook the meat (I think so.) and if there will be issues with bone rot.

Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to dry them in the fridge like that? Patting things dry with towels works quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alton Brown recommends brining pork chops in a salt water solution in one of his Good Eats episodes.

I have been brining them before I cook them ever since I saw that and think it makes them juicier.

I brine them for a couple hours at most and then just cook them. Never tried the drying in the refrigerator.